# What decides whether a static or object method should be called

Tags: java

Just a general query that came about by someone accidentally giving a variable of one class a name that matched another class where both had a method of the same name, one of which was static.

Given the following:

```
public class A {
    public static String dothis(String string){
        return "Class";
    }

    public static String dothis(String string, String string2){
        return "Class Method 2";
    }
}
```

and this

```
public class B {    
    public String dothis(String string){
        return "Object";
    }
}
```

Is it that the following will always call the object and not the static method once the object is instantiated?

```
System.out.println(A.dothis("..."));//outputs Class
B A = new B();
System.out.println(A.dothis("..."));//outputs Object
```

N.b. following instantiation it appears to be impossible to call any static methods in class A, i.e.

```
B A = new B();
System.out.println(A.dothis("..."));
System.out.println(A.dothis("...","..."));//Won't compile
```

the above won't compile complaining about an erroneous tree type,

**Edit:** added specific exception :-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at testbed.....
```

... does this mean the compiler is effectively deciding which method to call, so a difference javac version may behave differently.

What is going on here and if this is guaranteed could it be used for obfuscation in some way, or would decompilation remove the name clash?

Comment: That's why there are naming conventions :)

Comment: Define 'complains about an erroneous tree type'. Error messages should be quoted accurately and entirely,  not paraphrased into meaninglessness. And the compiler is quite entitled to complain about anything contrary to the JLS without it being automatically assumed that a different version is permitted to behave differently.

Comment: Man, that is quite a diabolic idea. Such a horrible hack that I almost like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing this:

```
B A = new B();
```

... the identifier `A` refers to the variable, not the class.

To avoid that being a problem, just don't do that...

> What is going on here and if this is guaranteed could it be used for obfuscation in some way, or would decompilation remove the name clash?

That entirely depends on the decompiler. If it's smart enough to recognize the issue, it could rename the local variable to one that doesn't clash.

Comment: Agreed. That's yet another good reasons to respect the Java naming conventions: classes start with an upper-case letter, whereas variables start with a lower-case one. So clashes like that are impossible if you respect the conventions.

Answer (score 2):

[Obscuring Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2) :

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that such a declaration is obscured.

In your example, A makes reference to the variable not the class. If the A class is inside a package, you still can access the static method using:

```
com.apackage.A.doThis("");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code B A=new B() is local object variable for class B , class A is hidden by this .

You two options:

Option 1: Use package name(namespace name)

```
    B A = new B();
    System.out.println(A.dothis("..."));
    System.out.println(Pack1.A.dothis("...","..."));//Class defined in Pack1 package .
```

Option1 : Rename the variable

```
    B Renamobj = new B();
    System.out.println(A.dothis("..."));
    System.out.println(A.dothis("...","..."));
```